# MSVC links against dynamic library with static library as linker input

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cmake

I have project, which links against OpenBLAS. In the project properties in Visual Studio I have in the "Additional Dependencies" setting the full path to `openblas.lib`, but MSVC still produces a binary which depends on openblas.dll.

The project is generated by CMake using the [OpenBLAS imported target](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/blob/develop/CMakeLists.txt) `OpenBLAS::OpenBLAS`, but I think for debugging purposes the most interesting question is, why MSVC does not link the objects from the file that is provided as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *.lib on Windows could be either an import library for a DLL or a static library.

A library in CMake is built with either `STATIC` or `SHARED` attribute. If it is **omitted** by default on Windows platform a shared library is built. This can be changed by definition of `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` on the CMake command line.

As you posted the CMakeLists.txt from OpenBLAS you are building a DLL on Windows platform by default. So the lib you are linking to is an import library.

**TL;DR**: To build OpenBLAS as static library you need to pass `-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF` on the CMake command line when running the configure step.